# NOT IN Condition Returning Unexpected Results

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are trying to create a report to identify active patients who don’t have any future appointments on the schedule. An active patient would be someone that had an appointment within the last year. My thought was to create a temp table with all patients that have been seen within the last year and then use the NOT IN condition to exclude them from my next query.  It is not producing the desired result.

**The following query lists all patients that have been seen in the last year that are not a cancellation or a no show.**

```
SELECT Patient_ID
INTO #TempPreviousAppt
FROM Appointments
WHERE Appointment_DateTime > DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())
AND Status NOT IN ('X','N')
GROUP BY Patient_ID
```

This produces 48,489 results

**The following query lists all patients with a future appointment.**

```
SELECT Patient_ID
INTO #TempFutureAppt
FROM Appointments AS Appt
WHERE Appt.Appointment_DateTime > GETDATE()
AND Status != 'S'
GROUP BY Patient_ID
```

This produces 4,683 results

**When I try to determine if a previously seen patient has a future scheduled appointment using the following query.**

```
SELECT Patient_ID 
FROM #TempPreviousAppt
WHERE Patient_ID NOT IN
(SELECT ISNULL(Patient_ID ,'')
FROM #TempFutureAppt)
```

It produces 43,843 results. I am not sure what I am missing.  Is the logic of the query not "Show all patients that had a previous appointment that don't have a future one"?

Comment: NOT IN (select *....) is not valid sql-server syntax (a single field name is needed after the SELECT), that query should not run. Please change either the query, or your dbms tag.

Comment: You don't need a temp table here, you probably could just use a CTE or subquery in your actual query.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis - `IN (select *....)` will wotk if inner table have only one column

Comment: wow, you learn something new every day! thanks

Comment: I previously did a subquery but when it too produced zero results I went with the temp table. In the end, I may just be going about this the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text criteria says

> An active patient would be someone that had an appointment within the last year.

But your query indicates that an active patient is someone who has had an appointment within the last year OR who has one scheduled any time in the future:

> WHERE Appointment_DateTime > DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())

The query below assumes the text description, not the query description. Given that, an `EXISTS` correlated sub-query should get you where you want to be.

```
SELECT 
   Appt.Patient_ID
  ,Pat.Patient_Number
FROM 
  Appointments AS Appt
JOIN 
  Patients AS Pat 
    ON 
      Appt.Patient_ID = Pat.Patient_ID
WHERE 
  Appt.Appointment_DateTime !< GETDATE()
  AND 
  EXISTS
    (
      SELECT 
        1
      FROM 
        Appointments AS a2
      WHERE
        a2.Patient_ID = Appt.Patient_ID
        AND
        a2.Appointment_DateTime >= DATEADD(year,-1,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
        AND
        a2.Appointment_DateTime < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
      AND 
        a2.Status = 'X' 
        OR 
        a2.Status = 'N'
    )
```

**Edit**

Sorry I didn't think "down and dirty" in the first place.

Setup:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
(
  Patient_ID INT,
  Appointment_DateTime DATETIME
);

INSERT @t
VALUES
  (1,'20181001'),
  (1,'20181115'),
  (2,'20171204'),
  (3,'20190101');
```

- Patient 1: Past appointment AND future appointment. So we don't care.
- Patient 2: Past appointment, NO future appointment. We care.
- Patient 3: Only a future appointment. We don't care.

Query for patients who've had appointments in the last year (notice there's an end date of 'GETDATE()', which is missing in the query above. May or may not matter. Not sure).

```
SELECT
  Patient_ID
FROM
  @t AS appt
WHERE 
  appt.Appointment_DateTime >= DATEADD(YEAR,-1,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
  AND
  appt.Appointment_DateTime < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Results:

```
+------------+
| Patient_ID |
+------------+
|          1 |
|          2 |
+------------+
```

Query for patients with a future appointment:

```
SELECT
  Patient_ID
FROM
  @t AS appt2
WHERE 
  appt2.Appointment_DateTime > CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Results:

```
+------------+
| Patient_ID |
+------------+
|          1 |
|          3 |
+------------+
```

Query for patients with a past appointment, but no future appointment:

```
SELECT
  Patient_ID
FROM
  @t AS appt
WHERE 
  appt.Appointment_DateTime >= DATEADD(YEAR,-1,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
  AND
  appt.Appointment_DateTime < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
EXCEPT
SELECT
  Patient_ID
FROM
  @t AS appt2
WHERE 
  appt2.Appointment_DateTime > CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Results:

```
+------------+
| Patient_ID |
+------------+
|          2 |
+------------+
```

Comment: Sheesh... I am confusing myself now!  Text criteria would be all patients that had an appointment in the last year but do not have a future appointment. Do I compare the patients in:

      SELECT Patient_ID
      FROM Appointments
      WHERE Appointment_DateTime > DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())
      AND Status != 'X' OR Status != 'N'
      GROUP BY Patient_ID

With all the patients with future appointments?

      SELECT *
      FROM Appointments 
      WHERE Appointment_DateTime > GETDATE()
      AND Status = 'S'

Answer (score 0):

you dont need temp table by common table expression you do same job

```
with cte1 as
(
  SELECT Patient_ID 
  FROM Appointments
  WHERE year(Appointment_DateTime)= year(getdate())-1 -- will last year records
  AND Status = 'X' OR Status = 'N'

), cte2 as
(
  SELECT Appt.Patient_ID, Pat.Patient_Number
  FROM Appointments AS Appt
  JOIN Patients AS Pat ON Appt.Patient_ID = Pat.Patient_ID
  WHERE Year(Appt.Appointment_DateTime)>year(getdate())-1 -- will pick except last year
  AND Appt.Patient_ID NOT IN (SELECT Patient_ID FROM cte1)
) select * from cte2
```

Same task you can do by using left join

```
with cte1 as
    (
      SELECT Patient_ID 
      FROM Appointments
      WHERE Year(Appointment_DateTime)= year(getdate())-1 --this will pick last year data
      AND Status = 'X' OR Status = 'N'

    ), cte2 as
    (
      SELECT Appt.Patient_ID, Pat.Patient_Number
      FROM Appointments AS Appt
      JOIN Patients AS Pat ON Appt.Patient_ID = Pat.Patient_ID
      WHERE year(Appt.Appointment_DateTime) > year(getdate())-1

    ) select cte2.* 
      from cte2 left join cte1 on cte2.Patient_ID=cte1.Patient_ID
      where cte1.Patient_ID is null
```

But from your query i got the point why you are not getting data `WHERE Appt.Appointment_DateTime < GETDATE()` you have to change this condition

Comment: I am still getting zero results for some reason. There is no way that every patient seen within the last year already has another appointment scheduled. I must be missing something. :-/

Comment: @GMR  you condition Appt.Appointment_DateTime < GETDATE() is the misleading content so far that i got because it will rerun all the patientid less than today so all patient will both table so it return empty change this condition

Comment: @GMR i change that to condition to year function

Comment: Ugh, maybe I am doing it incorrectly? I want a list of all patients that have been seen in the last year that don't have a future appointment. Wouldn't I want the condition to be patients with an appointment greater than today but not those in the list created in the first query?

Comment: @GMR i changed your condition please check

Answer (score 0):

`NOT IN` has unusual behavior when *any* value returned by the subquery is `NULL`.  In that case, `NOT IN` returns *no rows at all*.  I think that is the behavior you are seeing.

I strongly recommend always using `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN` because of this:

```
SELECT Appt.Patient_ID, Pat.Patient_Number
FROM Appointments Appt JOIN
     Patients Pat
     ON Appt.Patient_ID = Pat.Patient_ID
WHERE Appt.Appointment_DateTime !< GETDATE() AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #TempTableG t WHERE t.Patient_ID = Appt.Patient_ID);
```

I would also note that `>=` is much, much more common than `!<`.

Answer (score 0):

Due to your question, try LEFT JOIN such as this:

```
SELECT Appt.Patient_ID, Pat.Patient_Number
  FROM Appointments AS Appt
  LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT Patient_ID
      FROM Appointments
      WHERE Appointment_DateTime > DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())
      AND Status = 'X' OR Status = 'N'
      GROUP BY Patient_ID
  ) AS Pat 
  ON Appt.Patient_ID = Pat.Patient_ID
  WHERE Pat.Patient_ID IS NULL
```

If you provide soma sample data I can test the code.